# HTML EventSource not closing in electron app

Tags: html, electron, eventsource

Below code works fine in Browser. But when used in electron the event source not closing.

```
 var source = new EventSource("http://localhost/hyperion_datasource/events/powerup_events.php");
    var data=[];
    source.onmessage = function (event) { 
         data = event.data.split("$");
         console.log(data[0]);    
        if (data[0] > 99) {  
            console.log('closing stream'); 
            source.close();
        }

    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After calling `close()`, also set the value to null. It can then be destroyed and garbage-collected.

```
 var source = new EventSource("http://localhost/hyperion_datasource/events/powerup_events.php");
    var data=[];
    source.onmessage = function (event) { 
         data = event.data.split("$");
         console.log(data[0]);    
        if (data[0] > 99) {  
            console.log('closing stream'); 
            source.close();
            source = null;
        }

    };
```

I suspect you should be doing this for it to work reliably across all browsers, too. The difference in behaviour could also be due to different scope when running it in an Electron front-end, perhaps.

Comment: Thanks for advice.

Comment: But the problem was somewhere else in my code. Other function was triggering this EventSource after closing the source.

Comment: @PrakashKrishnan That is another reason to set `source` to `null`: then your whole code block can be wrapped in a `if(source===null){...}` to prevent double-connections. (Or you do an error message if source is not null; i.e. depending on if two calls to that bit of code are allowed or not.)